# Can't show specific properties when connecting to office 365

Tags: powershell, office365, select-object

so I'am writing a script to automate connection to o365 and exchange online, i was able  to do that, then the script spouse to show me specific properties and from some reason it's selection only one property

```
$getusrname = read-host "what is the user name?"

Get-Mailbox -Identity *$getusrname* | ForEach-Object { write-host -ForegroundColor White "I found these users: $_"} | select name, @{n="Email adress";e='UserPrincipalName'}
```

I'am getting this output:

```
 I found these users: Lev Leiderman
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that you have the order wrong, since `write-host` only outputs stuff to the console window and sends nothing through to the pipe.

Secondly, the `UserPrincipalName` you use is **not alway**s exactly the same as the users `PrimarySmtpAddress` (could be, but not always the case)

I think this would get you further:

```
$getusrname = Read-Host "what is the user name?"

# instead of using a Filter, you can also experiment with the '-Anr' parameter
# to perform an ambiguous name resolution (ANR) search.
# See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/get-mailbox?view=exchange-ps#parameters
$users = Get-Mailbox -Filter "Name -like '*$getusrname*'" | 
         Select-Object Name, @{Name = "Email adress"; Expression = 'PrimarySmtpAddress'}
if ($users) { 
    Write-Host "I found these user(s):"
    $users | Format-Table -AutoSize
}
else {
    Write-Host "No user found for $getusrname" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it's indeed working but it's too much lines for such "poor task" 

may you tell me what is the difference between "-filter" and "-identity" ?

Comment: @WebsGhost Too many lines? It is a bad thing to try and slam everything in one-liners because as you noticed, with those it is very easy to make mistakes and hard to detect them. `-Filter` can use wildcard characters like `*`. For `-Identity` you need to exactly specify the mailbox. See [Get-Mailbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/get-mailbox?view=exchange-ps#parameters)

Comment: I have to admit, there is a point..

i've tried the `-anr` and it' didn't worked by the way.

Comment: @WebsGhost With `-Anr` you cannot use the wildcard `*` characters. Have you looked at the official documentation I have linked to?

Comment: Yes my friend i had some spelling mistakes :) 

thanks !

Comment: @WebsGhost Great, glad to have helped.